# Define a CIContext as a NSObject property to reuse

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

OSX ELCapitan, XCode8.2, Objective-c Cocoa project.

In one of my NSobject classes, a method needs a CIContext, to render a CIImage bitmapdata to memory (CIContext render toBitmap). This method called frequently, so speed is an important factor. Since creating a CIContext to every rendering is very speed consuming, i tried to create a CIContext property, init in the class init, and just call it in the method as self.context.

But if I do it in this way, I get a BADEXECESS error message at the rendering command of the CIContext.
If I put the declaration and the initialization in the method, and create a CIContext every time, when this method calls, everythings works fine. 
If I declare it anywhere else, causes error.

```
@interface myClass:NSObject
@property CIContext *ciContext;
@end

@implementation myClass

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    _ciContext = [CIContext context];
    //self.ciContext = [CIContext context]; same result
    return self;
}

-(void)myMethod {

    [_ciContext render:xxx toBitmap:xxx rowBytes:xxx bounds:xxx format:xxx colorSpace:xxx];
    //[self.ciContext render:xxx toBitmap:xxx rowBytes:xxx bounds:xxx format:xxx colorSpace:xxx]; same result

}
```

Causes BADEXCESS. The following doesn't work either:

```
@interface myClass:NSObject
@end

@implementation myClass {
  CIContext *ciContext;
}

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    ciContext = [CIContext context];
    return self;
}

-(void)myMethod {

    [ciContext render:xxx toBitmap:xxx rowBytes:xxx bounds:xxx format:xxx colorSpace:xxx];

}
```

But:

```
@interface myClass:NSObject
@end

@implementation myClass

-(void)myMethod {

 CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext context];
 [ciContext render:xxx toBitmap:xxx rowBytes:xxx bounds:xxx format:xxx colorSpace:xxx];

}
```

Works perfectly.

???

How can I solve this? How can I create a reusable CIContext of my class? Or really, I have to create a new one, every time I call the method to use?

Comment: This line doesn't give you an error `@property ciContext *CIContext;`? Usually property definitions are `@property [class] [variable name]` so I think you have them flip-flopped, try `@property CIContext *ciContext;`

Comment: Oh... just a typo, thank you. My fault. Edited in the code above.

Comment: What happens when you use the property as  `self.ciContext` vs the private instance `_ciContext` . I’m wondering if the ARC is going wrong here. Unless you have a specific reason e.g. side effects , it’s best to use a property as a property.

Comment: It looks like your `NSobject` casing is incorrect as well, it should have a capital `O`, that should produce an error as well. It could be worthwhile to log your ciContext prior to calling the render method to determine if it isn't be initialized as you expect: `NSLog(@"ciContext = %@", _ciContext);` Additionally I would recommend adding the code that's creating your `myClass` and calling your `myMethod`. If _ciContext is properly initialized perhaps it's one of the parameters that you're passing to it that could be incorrect?

Comment: NSObject casing corrected, thank you. It seems, I was so frustratred by this problem, I simply forgot to type...:)

Comment: _ciContext or self.ciContext doesn't make a difference. If I NSLog it, the context not nil, I got its pointer back normally in both cases. The only difference is the place of the initialization. If it's in the method itself, everything works fine, but creates a new CIContext instance at every call. If I put the initialization anywhere else, it crashes. Weird...

Comment: _Ancient_ El Capitan. Are you using MRC or ARC? It's a long time ago I used MRC, but IIRC `@property` was by default `assign`, not `retain`/`strong` as it is with ARC. This can be your issue. Try to declare your property as `@property (nonatomic, retain) CIContext *ciContext` & use `self.ciContext`. I wrote an answer with full example, but because I don't have El Capitan around, it's ARC & latest greatest.

Comment: Using ARC and it's active. I tried to declare as (nonatomic, retain), perhaps the problem is in the default @property attributes, but the result was just the same...

Answer (score 0):

### Warning

> OS X El Capitan, Xcode 8.2

I don't have OS X El Capitan around. Following code was tested on macOS Catalina & Xcode 11.5 with ARC enabled (you should be able to use ARC as well, fully supported since OS X Lion IIRC).

### Comments

- Based on comments - I really wonder if your sample code is the real code (`@property ciContext *CIContext`, ...).
- Do not use `myClass` for class name, it should really be `MyClass`.

### CIContext

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext?language=objc) quote:

> `CIContext` and `CIImage` objects are immutable, so multiple threads can use the same `CIContext` object to render `CIImage` objects. However, `CIFilter` objects are mutable and thus cannot be shared safely among threads. Each thread must create its own `CIFilter` objects, but you can pass a filter’s immutable input and output `CIImage` objects between threads.

So, the `CIContext` & `CIImage` can be used from multiple threads without any issues.

### Example

Calculate average color for *100* images.

`ImageProcessing.h`:

```c
@import CoreImage;
@import AppKit;

@interface ImageProcessing : NSObject

+ (nonnull instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (nullable NSColor *)averageColorOf:(nonnull CIImage *)image;

@end
```

`ImageProcessing.m`:

```c
#import "ImageProcessing.h"

@interface ImageProcessing ()

@property (nonnull, nonatomic, strong) CIContext *context;

@end

@implementation ImageProcessing

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static ImageProcessing *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t token;

    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    _context = [CIContext context];
    return self;
}

- (NSColor *)averageColorOf:(CIImage *)image {
    CIVector *extent = [[CIVector alloc] initWithX:image.extent.origin.x
                                                 Y:image.extent.origin.y
                                                 Z:image.extent.size.width
                                                 W:image.extent.size.height];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAreaAverage"
                                  keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, kCIInputExtentKey, extent, nil];

    CIImage *output = [filter outputImage];

    if (output == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB);
    if (colorSpace == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    char bitmap[4] = {0};

    [_context render:output
            toBitmap:&bitmap
            rowBytes:4 bounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
              format:kCIFormatRGBA8
          colorSpace:colorSpace];

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:(CGFloat)bitmap[0] / 255.0
                               green:(CGFloat)bitmap[1] / 255.0
                                blue:(CGFloat)bitmap[2] / 255.0
                               alpha:(CGFloat)bitmap[3] / 255.0];
}

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`:

Put it anywhere, I just used application delegate, because I had opened another sample project.

```c
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ImageProcessing.h"
#import "pthread.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *queue;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    _queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 10;
    _queue.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUtility;

    // Be aware that this is an image from bundle, not from Assets
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"image" withExtension:@"png"];
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            mach_port_t threadID = pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self());            
            NSColor *color = [[ImageProcessing sharedInstance] averageColorOf:image];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4lu - %08x - %@", (unsigned long)i, threadID, color];
                NSLog(@"%@", output);
            });
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Output:

```
...
   84 - 00003f03 - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
   89 - 0000d217 - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
   98 - 0001470b - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
   99 - 00007b07 - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
   97 - 0000d313 - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
   94 - 00003a07 - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
   91 - 00001907 - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
   95 - 00014f13 - sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace -0.501961 -0.180392 -0.45098 -0.00392157
...
```

Comment: O.k. I understand your avg color code. But, if I understad the logic,  your ImageProcessing object is a singleton. Am I right? But in my code, I need several instances of the object holds the CIContext. Therefore, it cannot be a singleton...

Comment: And yes, that isn't my actual code, you're right. That's just a skeleton of the logic of my problem typed into the editor here, for easier read.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can create as many instances as you want. It just demonstrates that it works in multithreaded environment. You should really update your question with real code that exhibits the issue you have and show what are you really doing.

Comment: hm. Thaks for the link zrzka. I should have known those suggestions first...